# wrong repeated elements when to expand emmet expression into html

Tags: html, css, vim, emmet

I want to expand the expression :

ul.nav>(li.logo>img)+(li>a)*2

into one element `<li class='logo'><img></li>` and two same elements  `<li><a href=''></a></li>`

My expectation output is as below:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="logo"><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Why the real expanded output is as following:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="logo"><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li class="logo"><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

?

Comment: that's interesting cause I'm getting your desired outcome with the expression. I'm on vsc

Comment: `ul.nav>li.logo>img^(li>a)*2` here's another way to write the expression that you can try

Comment: @Selo it doesn't work in emmet-vim, which is the question. Your suggestion works in Vim, though.